# Calculate determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have tried to do this one two times, failed both. Correct answer is $$-90.$$

Here are [my attempts](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/13tm9mqgmn4xn9r/-fy6B0AHjv#lh%3anull-IMG_0057.JPG).

The matrix in question is

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1 & 3 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 2 &  1 & 2 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & -3 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
1 & -2 & 3 & -1 & -2 
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) is useful for boring computations.

Comment: I think the point here is the *process*, @TooOldForMath. jacob knows the answer. Wolfram is fine, once you've got that process "down pat." I try to encourage understanding the concepts and tools, not relying on calculators to get around learning those concepts and tools.

Comment: I found $42$ too.

Comment: I found 42, as well. You did fine on your first attempt. Good work. (The solution must have been be a typo/misprint.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt, which produced the answer $42$, was entirely correct.  Your mistake in the second attempt appears to occur at the bottom of the third image:  Where you have the determinant of the matrix

$$\pmatrix{0&1&1\\-1&-3&2\\2&1&4}$$

you should instead have the matrix

$$\pmatrix{1&-1&2\\-1&-3&2\\2&1&4}$$

Everything else there seems to be fine.  What made you think the "correct" answer is $-90$?

Comment: put it into a calculator. guess I was too tired. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your work, and both the first process you used to compute the determinant and your first solution are correct.

[Wolfram Alpha agrees with us, too.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant%20%7B%7B1,0,%E2%88%921,2,1%7D,%7B3,2,0,1,%E2%88%922%7D,%7B%E2%88%921,1,%E2%88%923,1,3%7D,%7B0,2,1,0,%E2%88%921%7D,%7B2,1,2,4,%E2%88%922%7D%7D)

Comment: But the OP got two different answers in his two attempts!

Comment: He didn't say "both processes", he said "both the process ... and the solution".